# Removing dtype from the end of numpy column stack

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists:

```
secondary_data = np.column_stack((user_secondary,_id_secondary))
primary_data = np.column_stack((user_primary,_id_primary))
```

that take in two other lists. When I output the difference between the lists using the following command:

```
[x for x in secondary_data if x not in primary_data] + [x for x in primary_data if x not in secondary_data]
```

or the following command:

```
filter(lambda x: x not in primary_data, secondary_data) + filter(lambda x: x not in primary_data, secondary_data)
```

I get the following value:

```
[array(['id5', 'value'], 
  dtype='|S32')]
```

Is there a way of making it only output the array:

```
['id5', 'value']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `tolist` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's a way to do that:

```
p0_1 = [x for x in primary_data if x not in secondary_data]
p1_1 = ' '.join(map(str, p0_1))
```

Comment: How about `[str(x) for x in primary ...]` or ' '.join(str(x) for x in p0_1]`?  Anything you can do with a `map` you can also do with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use [`tolist`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ7fn6xbjKAhUJ8HIKHaYyB9gQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.ndarray.tolist.html&usg=AFQjCNH3UQFJfTHefZlFW-BCdHH9vqV7pA) method of `numpy.ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.array(['id5', 'value'], dtype='|S32')]

result = a[0].tolist()

print(result)
[b'id5', b'value']
```

I'm using python 3 so for that case I could convert bytes to string:

```
result2 = list(map(bytes.decode, a[0].tolist()))

print(result2)
['id5', 'value']
```

Comment: I'm new to python so I'm unfamiliar with the In and Out notation. However, that seems like it only converts one output at a time. Is there a way of converting the whole array if it had more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned about values that you can use in other code, or in the display?

The `dtype` is included in the `repr` display, but not in the `str` one:

```
In [642]: x=np.ones((2,3),dtype='i,S4')
In [643]: x
Out[643]: 
array([[(1, '1'), (1, '1'), (1, '1')],
       [(1, '1'), (1, '1'), (1, '1')]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<S4')])
In [644]: print(x)
[[(1, '1') (1, '1') (1, '1')]
 [(1, '1') (1, '1') (1, '1')]]
In [645]: print(str(x))
[[(1, '1') (1, '1') (1, '1')]
 [(1, '1') (1, '1') (1, '1')]]
```

`tolist` converts the array to a list.  In this case a list of tuples:

```
In [646]: x.tolist()
Out[646]: [[(1, '1'), (1, '1'), (1, '1')], [(1, '1'), (1, '1'), (1, '1')]]
```

Comment: thank you, but I already figured it out. I posted my answer above.